# why Injected bean ApplicationScope is not followed by producer

Tags: java, cdi

I have a classes Triangle, DrawingTool, Main class and a producer class called MyProducer. Producer class has a method which is injecting Triangle instance in to DrawingTool class. I have provided no scope (default is @Dependent) to producer method and DrawingTool class. However, I have @ApplicationScoped annotation specified for Triangle class. 
when I am looking up DrawingTool class twice, I am getting 2 different Circle instance injected to DrawingTool instances. why?
here is the code

```
public class DrawingTool {


 @Inject @ShapeType(value= ShapeNames.TRIANGLE)
   private Shape triangle;



public Shape getTriangle() {
    return triangle;
}


public void drawShape(Shape s)
{
       s.draw();
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
@ApplicationScoped

public class Triangle implements Shape{

private String color;

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

@Inject
private Logger logger;

 public void draw() {
    logger.info("drawing triangle " + color);
}

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 public class MyProducer {

 @Produces
 @ShapeType(value= ShapeNames.TRIANGLE)
 public Shape getTriangle( Triangle t)
 {
     t.setColor("green");
    return t;
 }

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public static void main( String[] args )
{


    Weld weld = new Weld();
    WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();

    DrawingTool tool = container.instance().select(DrawingTool.class).get();

    tool.drawShape(tool.getTriangle());
    // change property of triangle to check for instance
    tool.getTriangle().setColor("dark Green");
    tool.drawShape(tool.getTriangle());


    DrawingTool tool1 = container.instance().select(DrawingTool.class).get();

    tool1.drawShape(tool1.getTriangle());

    weld.shutdown();
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////

I am getting following output

INFO: drawing triangle **green**

INFO: drawing triangle **dark Green**

INFO: drawing triangle ***green***

I was expecting  last print to be *dark Green* as it should be same Triangle instance that should be injected in both the DrawingTool instances. please explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependant scoped beans essentially act the same way as if you had instantiated a new instance of the bean yourself with `new`. Producers override anything else that's already on a bean. Here you haven't added a scope to your producer so it's going to assume Dependent because you didn't specify that on the producer method. I hope that helps.

Comment: If producer overrides any scope that bean has, then, why would we need  atnew annotation when injecting bean in producer method argument? Triangle bean has @ApplicationScoped mentioned whereas DrawingTool bean and producer method which is injecting Triangle bean in DrawingTool has default dependent scope. so, I was expecting   that Traingle bean scope(application scope) would be respected by producer method. If I had wanted Traingle bean scope to be overriden, I would have mentioned atnew in method argument which I did not.

Comment: You have the Bean Triangle, but then it is being overridden by the producer, so what is actually injected is a new dependent scoped bean. You should be able to see this if you debug your application.